# Difference between the words of violent criticisms

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What is the exact difference between:

- revile
- castigate
- inveigh
- asperse
- culminate
- vituperate
- vilify

In what context are these words used?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean *fulminate* rather than *culminate*

Comment: Maybe he meant calumniate

Answer (score 1):

From how I understand it, they are used in similar circumstances - none of them pleasant - but they possess a slightly different level of severity and context.

revile - criticise and insult

> *I was reviled by the show of insincerity showed by my boss.*

castigate - express an intense feeling of disapproval towards someone, reprimand someone

> *'I can't believe they castigated you for such a petty little mistake!'*

inveigh - heatedly write or talk about something

> *My friend enjoyed inveighing **against** each attempt made by the local council to secure his vote.*

asperse - criticise someone's reputation or standing

> *He aspersed the very foundation of the institute and its workers.*

fulminate - passionately protest against something

> *The soldiers fulminated **against** the new strategy.*

vituperate - insult someone using intimidating language

> *The captain vituperated his crew for their lack of courage in the face of danger.*

vilify - to write or talk about someone in a derogatory way

> *Though he was yet to be charged with the crime, the press vilified him relentlessly.*

Hope that helps!